# How to call parent method from React Child using Super call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to be able to abstract the way React component logic works separate the view logic from the handlers

```js
class SuccessLabelWithIcon extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className = this.className + ' success-label';
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
          <div onClick={super.onClick}>&#9650;</div> // this works but fires initially too in StackBlitz but not in SO not sure why, but changing to clickHandler dosent work.
     </div>
  }
}

class Label extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className='plain-label';
  }

   clickHandler = () => {
     console.log('Inherited');
   }

   onClick() {
     console.log('Inherited');
   } 

   render(){
     return <span className={this.className}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SuccessLabelWithIcon/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[**Working StackBlitzLink**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inheritancers)

Am I wrong with this approach? If No why is this not working for clickHandler, what I am looking at is extending component to have logic and the render functions as separate all the Button clicks and methods will be executed in the parent so that we can have separation of logic and then maybe share code across React and RN, but that is secondary?

My best bet is the clickHandler is attached to some prototypical property of the parent class as it a bound method and the click works as it a normal method not bound to the component but can we bypass this and can we mitigate this problem? And fire method only on click

Comment: What do you mean by "not working on SO"? Have you thought about accessing the method using `this`?

Answer (score -1):

Yes as u have stated your approach is not correct, in React you want to share code usage by components composition instead of inheritance.

I'm gonna use something similar to your example to help you understand the concept, lets say you want to create a base component called IconButton which will be a button with text alongside an icon, and you want to reuse that component to create two more components DangerIconButton (this is a button with an icon that is meant to represent a dangerous situation like a delete operation), and you want to create a SuccessfulIconButton (a button where you want to represent a desired action)

now based on our requirements we see that the functionality across all the three components is the same, basically a click handler but what is different is the visual representation (the icon and the styles applied to the button).

lets create our base component

```
class IconButton extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return <button onClick={props.onClick} style={props.style}>
          <img src={props.icon} />
          <span>button text</span>
      </button>

   }
}
```

now our two other components will be much simpler, and will use that base component

```
class SuccessfulIconButton extends React.Component{
   render(){

     // notice how i'm creating this component by composition of other components
     // happyIcon and green are what makes this a successful butoon
     return <IconButton onClick={props.onClick} style={{background: 'green'}} icon={happyIcon} />

   }
}

class DangerIconButton extends React.Component{
   render(){

     // notice that i'm getting the onClick handler here through props, because u want the parent components of this component to have their specific handlers
     return <IconButton onClick={props.onClick} style={{background: 'red'}} icon={dangerIcon} />

   }
}
```

of course here u want better naming, and u still want to do some common styling for all your IconButtons like padding, and other stuff. but hopefully the concept came through

Comment: Yes i agree that this might not be the best approach , but i donot agree with the answer you have mentiond what you have shown is sending a icon as prop ideally should be render prop or children.  I am open to more ways how we can reuse code generally separate business logic and view logic . As render is what changes but logic will remain same between react and react native.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is one which is not recommend and maybe even an anti-pattern to react's compositional model. Refer to [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) section in the docs to see why composition is better over inheritance in react and how to handle some of the problem with composition where developers reach for inheritance. In your case, you should look at [Specialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization)

You should almost *always* extend React components from `React.Component`.

```js
class SuccessLabelWithIcon extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // Specialization
      <Label>Success</Label>
    )
  }
}

class Label extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

   clickHandler = () => {
     console.log('Inherited');
   }

   onClick() {
     console.log('Inherited');
   } 

   render(){
     return <span className="plain-label" onClick={this.onClick}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a forked working version of your stackblitz.
[**Working StackBlitzLink**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inheritancers-w3cjd1?file=index.js)

Comment: Yes this clarifies , but if want to have just render separate and the logic driving the view same and abstracted out are there any possible ways.?

Comment: You can create a wrapper/container component that will contain all the logic, and it will then render the component with UI details in its render, passing all the logic as props from the parent. The UI component will then be unaware of the data/logic, it will only know what it needs to display on UI and what handler to call when event is triggered(all passed as props). When moving to react native, you will just have to replace the component containing UI details and styles.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @hassaan-tauqir, its usually preferred to use composition rather than inheritance. But if you really want to do it, you can use the below code

```js
class Label extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.className='plain-label';
   }
   clickHandler = () => {
     console.log('Inherited');
   }

   onClick() {
     console.log('Inherited');
   } 

   render(){
     return <span className={this.className}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}

class SuccessLabelWithIcon extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className = this.className + ' success-label';
  }
  render(){
    return (<Label><div>
          <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>&#9650;</div> // this works but fires initially too in StackBlitz but not in SO not sure why, but changing to clickHandler dosent work.
     </div></Label>);
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SuccessLabelWithIcon/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The reason `clickHandler` doesn't work is because you are using `arrow functions` to define it (basically it's doesn't have your SuccessLabelWithIcon context, and has instead the context of `Label`).

You can make it a simple method or you can simply use it with `this` instead of `super` (since you are extending the component).

```js
class Label extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.className='plain-label';
   }
   clickHandler = () =>{
     console.log('Inherited');
   }

   onClick() {
     console.log('Inherited');
   } 

   render(){
     return <span className={this.className}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}

class SuccessLabelWithIcon extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className = this.className + ' success-label';
  }
  render(){
    return (<Label><div>
          <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>&#9650;</div> // this works but fires initially too in StackBlitz but not in SO not sure why, but changing to clickHandler dosent work.
     </div></Label>);
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <SuccessLabelWithIcon/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps you